# Cant make a variable be seen outside of a function in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, asynchronous, xlsx-populate

I need to make the *index_to_write* variable to be seen outside of the function. How can I make this possible?

```
const XlsxPopulate = require('xlsx-populate');
let found = false;
let i = 1;
let index_to_write = 0;
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("todo-list.xlsx")
    .then(workBook => {
        while (i <= 10 && found === false){
            const value = workBook.sheet("Do-Shopping").cell("A" + i.toString()).value();
            if (value === undefined) {
                found = true;
                index_to_write = i.toString();
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
console.log("A " + index_to_write + " is the first one to be free of data");
```

I tried to add `return index_to_write;` below the `index_to_write = i.toString();` but it does not resolve the problem.

Currently, it shows 0, as in the initialization, but it should print 4. How to repair it?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: no.. actually I saw it and read it before asking mine, it does not, but thank you. @ASDFGerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declare the variable outside of the function you can see it. If that was not the case, you would get undefined and not 0 as a result.

However XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync is an async function and returns a promise, and that will not neccesarily be run imediately when the method is invoked. Therefore your console line will run before the promise is resolved.

So the execution sequence would be:

```
1. let index_to_write = 0;
2. XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("todo-list.xlsx")
3. console.log("A " + index_to_write + " is the first one to be free of data");
4. then(workBook => { ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It should be after then , not before, but I managed it out! thank youuuu!!! didn't know this. They closed my question so I had to delete it, but I highly appreacite it!! Merry X-mas!